# connection is not private after starting recording http jmeter on https sites

Tags: jmeter

Any https site will display the "your connection is not private message".

Tryied everything.

cannot surf the web at all, except for http sites.

got installed the jmeter certificate, and still nothing.

I am trying to record my application that sends requests in http, no problem for now but soon we will change to https and this will be a problem

I followed the following steps:

install java, install jmeter, create http recording from template, set proxy on windows machine to localhost:8888, start recording, install the jmeter certificate on web browser (IE and Chrome).

please advice

Comment: have you tried firefox? its easier and always works for me, this might help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios

Comment: @Limbo You can try in Firefox and also you can use Chrome Addons / recorder https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en and https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-electron-script-recorder